# DOM changes with javascript aren't working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple drop down menu which will have two elements: "male" and "female". I'm using a button to have these elements become visible. The problem is that they become visible but only for a fraction of a second and go back to being hidden.

Here's my code:

```
<html> 
<head>

<title>
  Validation Form
</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>
  Validation Form
</h1>
<form id="contactForm" action="" >
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Validation</legend>
    <p>
  <label for="firstname">First Name</label> 
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"/>

</p>
<p>
  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label> 
  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />

</p>
<p>
  <label for="gender">Gender</label> 
  <input id="gender" name="gender" type="text" />

</p>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="btn_drop" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" style="display: none">
        <p id="drop_male">Male</p>
        <p id="drop_female">Female</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
  <label for="website">Website</label> 
  <input id="website" name="website" type="text" />

</p> 
<p>
  <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  <input type="reset" value="clear" />
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>

<script> 
  var dropBtn = document.getElementById("btn_drop");
  dropBtn.onclick = function () {
     // show all elements on clicking submit!
     var drop = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
     drop.style.display = 'block';

  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at you browser console. I assume you have an error because you didn't declare `myFunction`.

Please read this URL: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp and use one of described approaches.

Answer (score 0):

you can make this without javascript [live fiddle with css](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/w6nvpfsb/3/)

```
 <p>
    <label for="gender">Gender</label> 
     <select  id="gender" name="gender" type='select' >
       <option value="">Select Gender</option>
       <option value="male">Male</option>
       <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
     </p>
```